# Can't execute sudo apt-get update / upgrade

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, update, sudo

When i try to execute sudo apt-get update i receive the error:

W: The repository 'http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

My /etc/apt/sources.list contains:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

And /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list contains:

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
#deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/archive.raspberrypi.org/ jessie main ui
```

Any Sugestions?
Obs: I have TeamViewer installed and i try to remove it but i can't how i do this?

Comment: There's something missing here... what is the output of `grep -rn ^ /etc/apt/sources.*`

Comment: i gave up. I formatted my microSD and upgrade to Raspian-Strech.

Answer (score -1):

```
apt-get remove <package_name>
```

This command removes an installed package, leaving configuration files intact.

```
apt-get purge <package_name>
```

This command completely removes a package and the associated configuration files.

Type apt-get without any option too see all options available.

Comment: the problem is i don't know how the name of teemviewer package.

Comment: I try to remove with TeamViewer, teamviewer, Teamviewer and nothing

Comment: 'apt-cache pkgnames team' could have been used to read out the package name